# Exporting a gltf file with compression and UVs applied results in an error

Tags: export, error

I'm trying to export a model (airplane) as a gltf (embedded) file. This error comes up when exporting with the compression option selected (which I need, as I need my file to be below a certain size).
Note: I am on Blender 2.91.2.

[image]

The error only appears when trying to export the object with compression and UVs applied. When exporting with compression (no UVs), or vice versa with UVs and no compression, the object can be successfully exported.

[image]

Comment: Hello, please *always* provide all the details you think may be necessary for someone to answer your questions (rather than mention that will if needed). Please read the [tour] page, it has some useful information about how this site works. Thanks

Comment: If you can test on the latest version of Blender and still get this error, I would report this to the maintainers of the glTF addon here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO. As a workaround in the meantime, you can also export without compression and then add compression with glTF-Pipeline or gltfpack afterward.

Comment: One of the possibilities for my error could actually have been UVs overlapping, but I will certainly take your suggestion and try gftf-pipeline or gltfpack.